# Foreach not correctly updating view

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I'm struggling to get a simple one page application to work. After checking the various debugging tools in the browser I can see that it's correctly triggering the search and returning the JSON in the correct format. However, the `foreach` binding doesn't seem to trigger, and the table never populates.

The relevant HMTL:

```html
<!-- Folders -->
<ul class="folders" data-bind="foreach: folders">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, 
                   css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() },
                   click: $root.goToFolder"></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tickets grid -->
<table class="tickets" data-bind="with: chosenFolderData">
    <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Description</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: tickets -->
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.goToTickets">
            <td data-bind="text: id()"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: message()"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: is_active()"></td>
        </tr>     
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the script:

```
function WebticketViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.folders = ['All', 'Open', 'Closed'];
    self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
    self.chosenFolderData = ko.observable();
    self.chosenTicketData = ko.observable();

    // Behaviours    
    self.goToFolder = function(folder) { 
        self.chosenFolderId(folder); // Mark folder as selected
        self.chosenTicketData(null); // Stop showing a ticket
        $.get('search.php', { folder: folder }, self.chosenFolderData); // Fetch folder data and update view
    };

    self.goToTickets = function(ticket) { 
        self.chosenFolderId(ticket.folder); // Mark ticket as selected
        self.chosenFolderData(null); // Stop showing a folder
        $.get('search.php', { ticketID: ticket.id }, self.chosenTicketData); // Fetch ticket data and update view
    };

    // Show inbox by default
    self.goToFolder('All');
};

ko.applyBindings(new WebticketViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the observable function as a `success` callback for the ajax call. Don't do that. Instead, have a proper function handle the result. You already expect as much in your view, since the `tickets` seem to have observable properties.

Create a constructor function for tickets, something like this:

```
function Ticket(data) {
  this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
  this.message = ko.observable(data.message);
  this.is_active = ko.observable(data.is_active);
}
```

And handle the ajax call along these lines:

```
$.get('search.php', { folder: folder }, function(data) {
  self.chosenFolderData({
    tickets: data.map(function(d) { return new Ticket(d); })
  });
});
```

Here's a full demo:

```js
// Fake data:
$ = {
  get: function(url, data, callback) {
    if (data.folder && data.folder === "All") { callback([{id:1, message:"My Message AAAA", is_active:true}]); }
    else if (data.folder && data.folder === "Open") { callback([{id:1, message:"My Message BBBB", is_active:false}, {id:1, message:"My Message CCCC", is_active:true}]); }
    else callback([]);
  }
};

function Ticket(data) {
  this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
  this.message = ko.observable(data.message);
  this.is_active = ko.observable(data.is_active);
}

function WebticketViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.folders = ['All', 'Open', 'Closed'];
    self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
    self.chosenFolderData = ko.observable();
    self.chosenTicketData = ko.observable();

    // Behaviours    
    self.goToFolder = function(folder) { 
        self.chosenFolderId(folder); // Mark folder as selected
        self.chosenTicketData(null); // Stop showing a ticket
        $.get('search.php', { folder: folder }, function(data) {
              self.chosenFolderData({
                tickets: data.map(function(d) { return new Ticket(d); })
              });
        }); // Fetch folder data and update view
    };

    self.goToTickets = function(ticket) { 
        self.chosenFolderId(ticket.folder); // Mark ticket as selected
        self.chosenFolderData(null); // Stop showing a folder
        $.get('search.php', { ticketID: ticket.id }, self.chosenTicketData); // Fetch ticket data and update view
    };

    // Show inbox by default
    self.goToFolder('All');
};

ko.applyBindings(new WebticketViewModel());
```

```css
li:hover { cursor: pointer; color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- Folders -->
<ul class="folders" data-bind="foreach: folders">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, 
                   css: { selected: $data == $root.chosenFolderId() },
                   click: $root.goToFolder"></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tickets grid -->
<table class="tickets" data-bind="with: chosenFolderData">
    <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Description</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: tickets -->
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.goToTickets">
            <td data-bind="text: id()"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: message()"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: is_active()"></td>
        </tr>     
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've implemented the changes you made, along with the fake data, and the page functions correctly. I'm still not sure how to remove the fake data and have it reference my real JSON.

Comment: Solved the last step. It wasn't correctly guessing that the callback was JSON, so had to be explicitly stated in the .get function.